# Getting 2 monitors to work in Debian

Tags: debian, multi-monitor

I would like to setup dual screens.

I've done multiple searches but there is nothing beginner-friendly for me to grasp exactly what I need to do to get the setup working.

I've picked up a few commands and here's what I have:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I suspect I should see either one of the following connected since I have the second monitor plugged in correct?

```
  DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I seem to have an NVIDIA graphics card as per the following:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [Quadro K2000] [10de:0ffe] (rev a1)
```

Some system information:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.4 (wheezy)
Release:    7.4
Codename:   wheezy
```

How to set this up for what I need to do next?

Comment: You say the monitor is plugged in.  This may seem like a weird question, but is it on?  Have you tried restarting your computer with the monitor plugged in and on?  Somethings X server (what controls the display adapters) does not pick up hot-plugged display port connections.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: See George Vasilou's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325696/using-two-displays-on-debian/325732#325732), which got me up and running in no time.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you start your X server / session you might end-up with monitors enabled / disabled and it's hard to judge your case. I like simplicity so it's best to handle this by yourself with `xrandr`. That's what I do from my `.xinitrc` basically, but then I'm running X server directly as I choose to have a control over what is happening.

So, go with `xrandr`. It has a command-line interface allowing you to basically setup monitors to your liking (see `man xrandr`). For quick adjustments install `arandr` which is simple / minimal and desktop agnostic `xrandr` frontend but doesn't support all `xrandr` features. That's what I use to quickly change config usually just temporarily. Then I use `autorandr` to remember the exact setup under some profile name which gets automatically recognized depending on connected monitors (taking EDID info into account). I have just 2 profiles `dock` and `mobile`. Before I used to have bare `xrandr` shell scripts setting up monitors as I wanted, hooked up to window manager shortcuts so I could quickly switch between just laptop monitor and other setup I called "bigdesktop" etc.

This is what I do whenever I change anything about monitors and want to "refresh"; sole point is to reset bare essentials of particular X screen:

```bash
$ cat ~/bin/xscreen 
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(xserver-name)" = 'X' ]; then
    autorandr -c --force
fi

xset b off s off dpms 0 0 300
xsetroot -solid black
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
```

**Edit:**

I was wrong in impression that `xrandr` shows outputs which are not enabled as disconnected. It's some time I was playing with this.

Having a proprietary Nvidia driver I think is an issue, since that driver is not working well with `xrandr`. There should be `disper` utility instead. For example `autorandr` works apparently with `xrandr` and `disper` too (excerpt from README):

```
While the script uses xrandr by default, calling it by the name "autodisper"
or "auto-disper" forces it to use the "disper" utility, which is useful for
controlling nvidia chipsets. The formats for fingerprinting the current setup
and saving/loading the current configuration are adjusted accordingly.
```

Following might help too: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Multiple_monitors

Answer (score 0):

There are graphical tools to assist you with this task. Most desktop environments come with their own so you dont need to use the console. Just google for your DE and multi screen.

A more independent tool is `arandr`, which will draw you a rectangle for each screen you have and you can arrange the rectangles to match the layout you want. Click apply and you get the layout of your chooseing. Of course you can save your layout as well. `arandr` saves layouts as `xrandr` calls, so you can simply source yout saved layout in `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession` or any other "autostart" facility you want, to enforce your layout at login.

However, you have another problem, because your xrandr output shows merely one connected screen. No piece of software for setting up dual screen will fix this issue. Google knows that this problem occationally happens with NVIDIA drivers. Which ones are you using? Maybe you need older or more recent drivers, or you try the open source nouveau drivers.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of things that may be the problem.

However after going through quite a long research period it turned out that having my VGA cable plugged (VGA was not connected to a powered up machine) into the monitor at the same time as the HDMI cable was preventing me  viewing the dual screen set-up properly.

So make sure that only one cable is connected to the monitor via the linux box.