# Using two displays on debian

Tags: debian, multi-monitor

I am trying to setup a dual screen configuration on debian 8 jessie with Gnome.

My computer has 3 graphical outputs : 2 displayport and 1 HDMI. I can't manage to have two of this 3 outputs to work simultaneously.

output of `xrandr` is (with the other display on displayport):

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1680 x 1050, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1680x1050      0.00* `
```

output of `xrandr` is (with hdmi working):

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080      0.00*
```

I also tried to use both displayport but it does not work either.

output of `lshw -c videò`:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff  ioport:f000(size=64)
```

(with both screens connected via displayport)

output of `lspci -v -s0:0:2.0`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1912 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 06b9
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Debian 8 as released doesn't support mobile Broadwell or later very well, and you've got a Sky Lake system.

To fix things, you need to upgrade your kernel, using [Jessie backports](https://backports.debian.org/), and install firmware to enable full graphics support (so you'll be adding the non-free backports repository).

First you need to add Jessie backports to your repositories, if it's not already there:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

(as root), then

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64 firmware-misc-nonfree
```

will install the current default backported kernel (4.7 as of this writing) and the accompanying firmware.

Once you've done that, you can remove [`xserver-xorg-video-intel`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/xserver-xorg-video-intel) (nowadays Intel GPUs don't need a separate driver, they can use the kernel's mode-setting support):

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Enabling backports is safe: newer packages are not picked up automatically from backports, you need to explicitly select them using `-t jessie-backports` as above (but once you've done that, updates to the upgraded packages are picked up by `apt-get upgrade`).

Comment: Stephen, the dual display works fine, but I think http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351390/202106 is related, do you have any clue about it? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In a similar system, I've succeeded in setting up two output which works great for any purpose (i.e watching videos in both screens).

For mirror screens:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 0.711x0.711
# Actually the whole desktop is 1366x768 , VGA-1 mode is set 1920X1080 but scaled (in reallity looks a little bit enlarged) to match 1366x768.
```

For Extended Desktop:

First run `xrandr` to get a list of displays with correct names, and the supported resolution configurations; then replace `VGA-1` and `LVDS-1` AND the resolutions in the command below, to suit:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --left-of VGA-1
```

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1680 x 1050, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1680x1050      0.00*

Comment: @jmatthieu You didn't follow the instructions... did you?