# Get to work 2 monitors in debian9 xrandr error

Tags: debian, multi-monitor, xrandr

I am trying to get to work my two monitor in debian9. I try several things and nothing get to work. 
I have a new computer with two output, one VGA and the other HDMI. Both have a monitor conected and I see the same thing in both.
First I try the easy way that is to do it in:
system -> preference -> hardware -> monitors
And then there should be 2 monitors in the display but instead of that I get "monitor default unknown", and only one.
Then I try with "xrandr" and I get the error:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

This is the same problem as: [Using two displays on debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325696/using-two-displays-on-debian)

But I check and that answer is for debian8 and does not work in debian 9.  Then I try to catch my output with lspci and I get:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3ec2 (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a36d (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a36f (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a360 (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a352 (rev 10)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33c (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a33f (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a303 (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a348 (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a323 (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a324 (rev 10)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Computer specifications:

- Debian 9 (strech) 64 bits
  Núcleo Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64
  MATE 1.16.2
- Intel® Core™ i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz × 6
- motherboard H310M-E

And I see there is no HDMI port found. 
Does anybody know how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem. The problem was the stable kernell version in debian, when I updated the kernel to 4.19 (non-stable) both monitors work perfectly as expected.